# TinyMCE renders non editable after partial postback

Tags: .net, tinymce, updatepanel

I have recently integrated tinymce in update panels.

It works well in all major browsers except in Firefox (Tested with Firefox 12, 13b7 and the latest nightly 15a01). I also tested with Firefox 10, it does the same thing and just does not work with Firefox 4

I am using TinyMCE 3.5.2

Here is my workflow :

TinyMCE gets loaded correctly the first time and I can edit the content. However, when I do a partial postback, I can see that it gets loaded successfully (I can see the text appearing for like a second or two) and then after that it disappears and tinymce gets unusable. Meaning that I can't click in it, can't focus. However, I can modify the DOM manually and see the text.

My update panel contains a user control in which tinymce is loaded at page load using the following :

```
WebHelper.RegisterRichTextEditorInsideStartupScriptNoLoading(Page)
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upanel, upanel.GetType(), upanel.UniqueID, "tinymce.init();", True)
```

Where upanel is my UpdatePanel id and the link to tinymce is added using the web helper

Any ideas? It works well in IE 9, Chrome, Safari on windows and MAC.

I found this : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737784
Which looks like my problem but can't find any solution.

Thanks